How to use EXECUTE AS in a procedure without giving a USER explicit IMPERSONATE permissions?
I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2019. It truncates a staging table and then inserts data. I have granted User1 EXECUTE permissions for this stored procedure usp_insert_data.
However, when I execute the stored procedure, it fails because of the TRUNCATE. If I remove the TRUNCATE, it works OK. My understanding is that TRUNCATE can only be made by users with specific privileges, which I do not want to grant to User1.
I have created another user PowerUser, which I have given ALTER permissions to the table tbl_data, and then included the following code in my stored procedure:
EXECUTE AS USER = N'PowerUser';

TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_data];

REVERT;

My stored procedure now looks like this:
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_insert_data]
    @id bigint,
    @utc datetime,
    @latitude decimal(19,15),
    @longitude decimal(19,15)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE AS USER = N'PowerUser';

    TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_data];

    REVERT;

    INSERT INTO [tbl_data] (plot_id, utc, gmt,
                            latitude, longitude)
    VALUES (@plot_id, @utc,
            @utc AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time',
            @latitude, @longitude)
END;

But I still get the following error:

Msg 1088, Level 16, State 7, Procedure dbo.usp_insert_data, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 2]
Cannot find the object "tbl_data" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

To allow EXECUTE AS to PowerUser by User1, do I need to run this code:
GRANT IMPERSONATE ON USER:: [PowerUser] TO [User1]

which would mean the user could impersonate at will or am I doing something wrong?
Thanks

To use an EXECUTE AS statement within a stored procedure the USER/LOGIN needs explicit permission to impersonate that USER/LOGIN. Instead what you should be doing is defining the EXECUTE AS within the WITH clause of the procedure and defining the PowerUser USER in that clause. For example:
--Create a sample table
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (SomeID int IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_SomeTable PRIMARY KEY,
                            SomeString varchar(10),
                            SomeDate date,
                            SomeInt int,
                            TheUser sysname DEFAULT USER_NAME());
GO
--Create the sample user and a power user
CREATE USER SomeUser WITHOUT LOGIN;
CREATE USER PowerUser WITHOUT LOGIN;
GO
GRANT ALTER, INSERT ON dbo.SomeTable TO PowerUser; --Give the PowerUser the ability to ALTER and INSERT the sample table
GO
--Create the sample procedure that TRUNCATEs and the INSERTs into the table
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.SomeProc @SomeString varchar(10),
                                  @SomeDate date,
                                  @SomeInt int
WITH EXECUTE AS 'PowerUser' AS --now the proc will execute as the PowerUser                          
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable;

    INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeString, SomeDate, SomeInt)
    VALUES(@SomeString, @SomeDate, @SomeInt);
END;
GO
--Give the sample user permission to execute the proc
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.SomeProc TO SomeUser;
GO
--Impersonate our sample user
EXECUTE AS USER = N'SomeUser';
GO
--Run the proc
EXEC dbo.SomeProc 'abc', '20240621','123';
GO
--Run the proc again (this'll delete the original row) 
EXEC dbo.SomeProc 'def', '20240622','456';
GO
--Back to "us"
REVERT;
GO
--Check the data is the second data set, but will have an ID of 1, not 2.
SELECT *
FROM dbo.SomeTable;

GO
--Clean up
DROP USER SomeUser;
DROP PROC dbo.SomeProc;
DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable;

If you want to revert to the calling user within the procedure, you can use EXECUTE AS CALLER:
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.SomeProc @SomeString varchar(10),
                                  @SomeDate date,
                                  @SomeInt int
WITH EXECUTE AS 'PowerUser' AS --now the proc will execute as the PowerUser                          
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable;

    EXECUTE AS CALLER; --Now we're whoever ran the EXEC

    INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeString, SomeDate, SomeInt)
    VALUES(@SomeString, @SomeDate, @SomeInt);
    
    REVERT; --Isn't really needed, but to be "safe"
END;


I like this test script, it shows the whole principle. Would "WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER" be a useful and save alternative? Or should we always create a user "PowerUser" with permissions limited to the exact particular use?

I can't test at the moment, but I recall that OWNER did not grant the needed permissions to TRUNCATE here, @DerU .

If the sp owner is also db owner, then almost certainly does he have the ALTER permission (necessary for TRUNCATE) on the table (in the same db). If it's not the db owner we need to make sure that the user who owns the sp also has ALTER permissions on the table. Creating a separate user ("PowerUser") with all specific permissions, and only those, seems best.
